# React Firebase Axios : problem with saving the data to Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, axios

I am trying to create a Translation app in which I send the text to the api and then i receive the translation back with a text typing effect.

The problem arise when I save the words that I receive to Firebase with debounce function. **It always only save the initial part of the translation received** (let's say that I get a translation of 100 words, it saves only the first 10) and I can't really figure out why.

This is the function that I use to send the text to the api and then receive the translation back.

```
   handleClick(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    

    let body = {
      prompt: this.state.input
    };

    let thisComponent = this;
    
 axios.post(TRANSLATE_API_URL, body).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
  
  let wordDelay = 100  // Add a word every 100ms
  
  let timerDelay = 0
  text.split(" ")
    .forEach(word => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        thisComponent.setState({ input: thisComponent.state.input + " " + word });
      },timerDelay);
      timerDelay += wordDelay;
    });

   //Calling Firebase function
    this.updateBody(this.state.input);
}); 

}
```

And this is the code that I use to save data to Firebase .

```
  updateBody = async (val) => {
    await this.setState({ input: val });
    await this.setState({ wordsCounted :val.split(' ').length });
    await this.setState({charactersCounted : val.length })
    /*assign the number of words inside the textarea to the variable wordsCounted*/
    this.update();
  };
 update = debounce(() => {
    this.props.noteUpdate(this.state.id, {
      body: this.state.input,
 
    })
  }, 750);
```

The only explanation I have given myself is probably a problem with **asynch and await**.

Comment: I'm not sure where your exact problem lies, but it seems like it would be easier to translate all in one call and then do your word-by-word visual effect after you already have the results. You would then probably be able to get rid of the debounce, which is the most likely culprit for your saving issue.

If nothing else, your updateBody can be simplified. `setState` can modify all three values in one statement, and you can use the optional callback parameter to run your update function.

Comment: I solved it!!!!

Comment: Cool! Can you explain how, in case somebody else has a similar problem later?

Comment: The problem was that I had to increment the debounce duration because it actually after 1500ms it stopped to sending the words to save to Firebase.

Comment: By the way I encountered a new problem, if you want  you can help me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66988430/chart-problem-with-displaying-words-of-a-text-area-react-firebase